# How can I run certain programs without the debug/status window, such as Firefox from the command line?

Tags: linux, firefox, command-line, debian

`firefox` in Debian maps to iceweasel and invokes the program, however how can I get rid of the debug/status window and force it to act the same way as if I clicked on it in Applications -> Internet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`firefox &` should fire it up in the background.

Comment: the answer is fine, just a note of the difference between this way and the one i mentioned: if you leave the terminal open, you will still see messages from the process using this method.

Answer (score 3):

redirect stdout and stderr to dev null

firefox >/dev/null 2>&1